# Removing options from the customer account dashboard menu

Tags: customer-account, dashboard

I need to remove some options from the customer account dashboard menu (eg: billing agreements and Recurring Profiles). Where are these defined?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% if this is for the admin or frontend parts of Magento.

**For front end**

To remove items from the navigation what I would suggest would be to create your own module that rewrites the block `customer/account_navigation` and then create a new function `removeLink` which then can be called in the same way as the `addLink` call via layout xml.

Layout xml

```
<action method="removeLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name></action>
```

Code

```
public function removeLink($name){
    unset($this->_links[$name]);
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In admin `System/Permissions/Roles` remove them from the customer roles